# Some items of Parallel.ForEach<T> run on ThreadPool, some don't

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library, threadpool, parallel.foreach

I have a simple algorithm like this:

```
Parallel.ForEach(myList, new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4 } ,(job) => job.doSomething());
```

`myList` is a `List<MyType>`.

`MyType` has `void DoSomething()`.

inside `DoSomething` I check `Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread`.
Some threads aren't "ThreadPooled";

Comment: the first, and always with the same caller thread id. but if MaxDegreeOfParallelism > Logical Processor Count, that thread ID is used again...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The functions defined in `Parallel` will also use the thread you called the function from as one of the worker threads. Most likely the non Thread Pool threads where jobs done on the thread you called `Parallel.ForEach` from.

Comment: There's some overhead due context switch, no?

Comment: Yes, that is why they do it. By making the first worker work on the thread that called the method the worker can do its job without making a context switch. If there is only a few items in the collection it will be faster than sending work to the thread pool. Once it sees there is a lot of work to do it stats up thread pool helper threads but it still keeps using that first worker that is running on the calling thread.

Comment: Now i can see it! haha
Just made a simple algorithm to stress all cores, and lets go! "Main" thread comes and goes everytime. Thanks bro! +1